# C typecasting uint32 to uint16

Tags: c, static-cast

```
typedef struct a{
    uint32 val1;
    }A;

typedef struct b{
    uint16 copy_val1;
}B; 


void function1(A input)
{
    B my_input;

    my_input.copy_val1 = (uint16) input.val1; <-- Is this clean?
}
```

Inititally when struct a was designed, it was thought that val1 will contain two 16 bit values. However we chose to use only one 16 bit.

Now I am changing the copy_val1's type from uint32 to uint16 to save memory.
How should I typecast in a clean way and make sure that the 16 bit value from val1 get's copied to copy_val1?

The OS is vxworks in MIPS architecture.

Comment: Is your code not working? Casting like this should be fine.

Comment: MIPS is very sensitive to alignment, and the compiler has lots of leeway how it lays out elements in a struct (padding), so unless you pack it you might end up with not saving any memory at all. Also in my experience this is the kind of micro optimization that's not going to help you with any memory issues in the long run. As a matter of fact IMHO the best choice of type for an integer value where you don't have to hit a very specific size is just plain `int` (notable exception: 8 bit architectures like AVR where int8_t is the sane default choice).

Comment: Here's a much more important trick you can put into your program to help you with that tight memory: Somewhere place a `char memory_reserve[SIZEOF_MEMORY*5/100];` that's getting placed into the `.bss` section, i.e. shave of 5% of the memory you have available for your project. Eventually, in a few months from now, after long nights and every effort to squeeze out the last bits out of an array used by some algorithm that works on bulk memory, you can save the day, by taking some memory out of the reserve.

Comment: Caius: I haven't tested. But I think it would work fine. 
@datenwolf: The structure B is the format in which a network device sends information about flows going through the device. There are millions of flows sent in a day and any memory/bandwidth saving is appreciated.

Comment: @KingkongJnr: So it's saving bandwidth you're after. Fair point. However you should *never __ever__* use a raw struct for data that goes over a network. Networks (all of them!) are hostile environments. If you'd read directly into a struct its much easier for an attacker to exploit your program. Also endianess of struct fields becomes an issue. At least when receiving the proper way to interface with a network is through an intermediary flat buffer which you verify-parse into the actual struct. Note that in typical network applications you're usually going to be IO-bound, not CPU-bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply assigning the uint32 value to a uint16 variable, without a cast, is sufficient.

However, you run the risk of *truncation*. You should consider checking to see if `val1 > UINT16_MAX` before assignment.

Also note that for structures larger than one or two machine registers, you should pass *pointers* to structures. Otherwise you incurr a potentially large copy. Do note the change in semantics, however.

Comment: without a cast is sufficient? Am I guaranteed that the bits containing the 16 bit value gets copied and not all 0s?
The values that are stored in val1 are currently using only 16bit. So I should be ok with "risk of truncation".
Valid point about passing pointers to structures. This was a quick example. So I wrote it like this.

Comment: @KingkongJnr If you know that all the values are small enough to fit in 16 bits, it will be fine. Assigning from 32-bit to 16-bit simply discards the high-order bits.

Comment: A simple assignment will implicitly do exactly the same conversion that the cast would have done. Conversion of an integer to an unsigned type is well defined; it discards the high-order bits.

Answer (score 1):

That is clean. The old compilers would accept this even without the cast.
Just keep in mind that you pass only lowest 16 bits of the uint32 value.